# Oracle audit logs

Tags: oracle, security, oracle12c, audit

We are sending Oracle 12c audit logs to OS files but its generating huge amount of logs. How can we decrease generation of audit logs?

These are the audit log settings:

```
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
audit_file_dest                      string      /audit/auditlog/authentic/orac
                                                 leaudit.log
audit_sys_operations                 boolean     TRUE
audit_syslog_level                   string      LOCAL6.INFO
audit_trail                          string      OS
unified_audit_sga_queue_size         integer     1048576
```

We want audit logs at OS levels as per PCI-DSS. Please tell me how to view which audit logs are enabled so we can disable audit logs which are not required,

Comment: PCI-DSS deals with securing data about payment cards, including  restricting and auditing access to that data. Oracle's default AUDIT functionality is not a good fit for that duty. Do you mean Fine-Grained Auditing? Please provide more details regarding what you audit and how you go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Following setting will cause all Audit logs to OS filesystem:

```
audit_trail                          string      OS
```

Please set to following value, which will write most of the audit information in sys.aud$ table in database and only required OS audit logs will be created.

```
audit_trail = db, extended
```

On last note, please do clean up audit logs from OS filesystem & sys.aud$ table periodically.

- Abhi

Comment: but we want audit logs at OS levels as per PCI-DSS .please tell me how view which audit logs is enable.

Comment: so we can disable audit logs which does not required,

Comment: In this situation, you have two options : 1) Keep using audit_trail=OS . 2) audit_trail=OS, but identify the tables which will have sensitive information like credit card data etc & enable fine grained auditing with option of audit_trail=> DBMS_FGA, which will supress clear text in sys.aud$ table.

Comment: My main problem is apllication user generating huge records in os level file how to minimize that

Comment: Sorry, I was away for few days. My previous comment mention solution to minimize the OS level audit file generation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you read the OS audit log file and see what are the contents logged?

And if you think it is not necessary, then issue a "noaudit" command on the corresponding privilege not to be logged:

Eg:

```
NOAUDIT CREATE SESSION ;
NOAUDIT CREATE SESSION BY HR;
NOAUDIT UPDATE ANY TABLE ;
NOAUDIT UPDATE ANY TABLE BY hr ;
```

For more details see:

http://satya-dba.blogspot.com/2009/05/auditing-in-oracle.html